# AS3 TimerEvents - Child listening to Parent Timer Event

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I have my child have an `actionListener` that listens to a `TimerEvent` inside the parent?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just call a function in each child when the parent timer ticks? Basically just make your children implement an interface you create (let's call it `IHaveTickingParent`) that has a specific function, like this:

[IHaveTickingParent.as]

```
public interface IHaveTickingParent
{
    function onParentTick(event:TimerEvent):void;
}
```

[HaveTickingParentImpl.as]

```
public class HaveTickingParentImpl /* extends XYZ */ implements IHaveTickingParent
{
    public function onParentTick(event:TimerEvent):void
    {
    }
}
```

And in your parent's TimerEvent handler just do something along the lines of:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < numChildren; i++)
{
    var child:DisplayObject = getChildAt(i);

    if(child is IHaveTickingParent)
    {
        // Make children update as well.
        (child as IHaveTickingParent).onParentTick(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind I just modified to say use an interface instead of a subclass.  Either is an option but this leaves you open to subclass something else if necessary.

Comment: @shaunhusain Cheers, I do prefer to use interfaces here I just wanted to avoid introducing concepts that may confuse the OP at this stage.